# Tailwind CSS Utility Classes Are Not Working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build an Airbnb clone using nextjs and tailwindcss in VS code. My problem is that for some reason the utility classes are not working. The logo I added does not change the way it should. It should be in the left top corner so what is the reason for that? Is my setup wrong? I would appreciate the insight! Here is the link to the repository
https://github.com/fabioc1101/airbnb

Comment: Please include code that illustrates the problem in the question itself, preferably as a [mcve]. Don't make us go offsite and trawl through a depository to try and work out where it is.

Comment: I watched a video and I added a plugin called PostCSS Language support and now it is working properly. I did not know I needed a plugin since it was never mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading through the TailwindCSS with Next.js guide. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Now, I'm not going to tell you to do that without speculating on what might be wrong with your current setup.

You're missing this at the top of your `globals.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: it actually is there but it doesn't show up in the online repository. I don't know why. I have it at the very top of the global css and went through the guide multiple times. VS code tells me "unknown at rule" three times in my global css and the @tailwind elements are underlined.